# plotting two axis chart in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working on a project whose ultimate result is total production, lets represent this by `W`. The nature of `W` is such that it varies with `t` and `h`. With a lot of tweaks, I managed to obtain the following `df`.

```
sens <- structure(list(W = c(5216400.4123, 5399804.7349, 5595563.3087, 
5792353.9932, 5993467.7466, 6189404.9279, 6380940.454, 6566630.3544, 
6747453.6816, 6917820.9796, 7086201.8275, 7248213.5225, 5402700.4252, 
5592654.9057, 5795404.8549, 5999223.7818, 6207520.1695, 6410455.1037, 
6608831.1825, 6801152.8706, 6988434.1695, 7164886.0132, 7339280.46, 
7507078.2886, 5589000.4397, 5785505.0748, 5995246.3993, 6206093.5662, 
6421572.589, 6631505.2817), t = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("t_m75_tc", 
"t_m5_tc", "t_m25_tc", "t_p0_tc", "t_p25_tc", "t_p5_tc", "t_p75_tc", 
"t_p10_tc", "t_p125_tc", "t_p15_tc", "t_p175_tc", "t_p20_tc"), class = "factor"), 
    p = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("h_30", "h_27.5", "h_25", "h_22.5", 
    "h_20", "h_17.5", "h_15", "h_12.5", "h_10", "h_7.5", "h_5", 
    "h_2.5", "h_1", "h0", "h1", "h2.5", "h5", "h7.5", "h10", 
    "h12.5", "h15", "h17.5", "h20", "h22.5", "h25", "h27.5", 
    "h30"), class = "factor"), tt = c(-7.5, -5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 
    5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 20, -7.5, -5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5, 
    7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 20, -7.5, -5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5), 
    hh = c(-30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, -30, 
    -30, -30, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, 
    -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -25, -25, -25, -25, -25, 
    -25)), .Names = c("W", "t", "p", "tt", "hh"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is how the original df looks like. In the above reproducible data, I've included only 30 rows.

```
> str(sens)
'data.frame':   324 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ W : num  5216400 5399805 5595563 5792354 5993468 ...
 $ t : Factor w/ 12 levels "t_m75_tc","t_m5_tc",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ p : Factor w/ 27 levels "h_30","h_27.5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ tt: num  -7.5 -5 -2.5 0 2.5 5 7.5 10 12.5 15 ...
 $ hh: num  -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 ...
```

I need to plot `W vs tt and hh` in the same chart with two Y axis. I tried to plot with ggplot2 but I later learnt, ggplot doesnot support 2 y axes. Is there an another way to plot the data ? I would love something like these::  [image] [image]

Comment: You can plot them in separate facets with `facet_wrap` with `scales = "free_y"`

Comment: I am opting for something else .. faceting won't be good for me. I tried that and its not what I want @alistaire  If there's something else ??

Comment: Take a look at http://www.ggtern.com/

Comment: The `ggplot2` folks reluctantly added secondary axes in a release a few months ago, but something like `ggtern` would probably be more suitable.

Comment: yeah @camille but i thought, the secondary axis can only be some multiple or a functional derivative of first axis.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So if those axes are independent of one another, something like a ternary plot would be more appropriate. You could check through the [Data Viz Project](http://datavizproject.com/) for ideas of how you want to visualize multivariable data, then figure out a specific question on how to build that visualization

Comment: Plotting with two y axes that aren't just a conversion is in most cases misleading, which is why it isn't possible in ggplot. The usual alternatives are facetting and log scales. In this case, another option would be to map one of the y variables to another aesthetic like color, though obviously it's harder to see proportional differences that way. Line width/point size is another possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt with your data. Mind the scaling for the ternary axis

```
library(ggtern)
ggtern(sens, aes(x = W/max(W),z=tt/max(tt), y=hh/max(hh))) +
 geom_point(size=3, col='red') +
 theme_bw()
```

[image]

Just to add a powerful representation (as suggested in the comments).

```
ggplot(sens, aes(W, tt, group=hh, color=hh)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line(lwd=1) +
 theme_bw() +
 scale_color_continuous(low = "black", high="red")
```

[image]

I would also suggest surface plots.

```
require(rgl)  
surface3d(x, y, z)
```

Comment: the line chart would be not suitable, i have a large data. for ternary plot. . question 1, why use W/max(W) and not just W ? same for tt and hh

Comment: I scale the data so you can have all 3 axis being in a hypothetical scale from 0 to 1 (or 0 to 100%). There are other ways of scaling data or playing with the axis. I'd refer you to the documentation on `ggtern` for that. If you have plenty data, I might suggest a surface plot. It might depend on the 3D pattern (the data that you posted seems quite ordered)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by surface plot .. is it a 2D plot like the line plot that you posted ? And what do u mean by my data is ordered data ? Is it a bad thing ?

Comment: can you provide me links to some good documentation for surface plots ?

Comment: @anup Ordered as in you have a clear effect (lines are parallel to each other). There's no good/bad, it's just the nature of your data. You can goolge about surface plots, I just put a generic example. This question is getting a bit too broad and could be voted to be closed. The original question was how to do a ternary plot in R and I believe it has been answered.